# How to read ppt template and edit it according our need in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, text, frontend, powerpoint

In ReactJS we have one **ppt** template which we will download on frontend side. How to find the specific slide and **replace/insert** texts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are some links that might help you :
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pptx
https://codesandbox.io/examples/package/react-pptx